# Very disturbing pop up in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I don't know why, but since yesterday I have this kind of pop-up that follows my cursor when I write my code, it's SO disturbing! Does anyone know how to turn this stuff off? I had to accidentally activate it with a keyboard shortcut but no idea which one.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your settings, search for `editor.parameterHints.enabled` and untick the setting. Alternatively, in `settings.json`, add `"editor.parameterHints.enabled": false` (or set the key to `false` if it exists already).

You can still bring up the hints on demand using `Ctrl+Shift+Space`.